# App is rejected use of non-public URL scheme, which is a private entity

Tags: ios, swift, app-store

> Your app uses the "prefs:root=" non-public URL scheme, which is a private entity. The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App Store because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change.

If user off the location service then what we do?? because app required user's location.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the non-public URL schemes in your app. If you do, Apple will reject your app for the security and privacy reason. If you continue to do same, it will lead to permanently disable your apple developer account.

For the user location, you can always check for the permission for location either user has give it or not. And based on the user action you can take the further actions.

**How to check location permission**

```
import CoreLocation
```

Create location manager as property

```
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
```

Request for the location permission.

```
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
locationManager.delegate = self
locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

Implement the delegate `CLLocationManagerDelegate` to get the location permission.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

    switch status {
    case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:

        print("User has given location permission...")

        //do something 

    case .denied, .notDetermined, .restricted:
        print("Location permission is not given.")
       //do something when location permission is not given by user or it can't be determined.

    @unknown default:
        print("unknown case...")
    }        
}
```

**Do not forget to add required keys for location permission in `Info.plist` file.**

So in this way you can manage location permission and perform some operation.

When you upload app next time you need to remove non-public URL schemes otherwise you will face rejection again.

Comment: If iPhone location service if off then permission alert not show in this case what we do ?????????

Comment: You can directly detect that location services are off. You need to fail gracefully.

Comment: @Mahendra Sir, Thanks for reply I have use same but my concern is that If user's phone location is Off in this case I show alert message for ON location then Apple also rejected app and give this reason "We noticed that your app does not request and obtain the user's consent prior to accessing their location data, which is not allowed on the App Store." so what we do because my app required user's location.

Comment: You need to add user understandable msg  like `App wants to know your current location to show on map` for `Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description` key in plist file.

Comment: you need to show to user why are you user their location

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, please revise your app to provide the associated functionality using public APIs or remove the functionality using the “prefs:root” or “App-Prefs:root” URL scheme.

Comment: try this "URL(string:UIApplication.openSettingsURLString" but this will open app setting. And If in general setting, location service Off then In App setting location service is disable then what we do ?